# Architecture of basket in django

Tags: django, architecture

I want to create several baskets for ordering items. When i click on "add button" on item's page, i want it was added to my last basket. Baskets amount are several. I don't want select "basket" each time, when i want to add. I want it was selected and changed once somewhere (other page).

How should it work? I click basket#1 and then i go add items to this basket.
Then i go to basket#2 and add.
And i cannot make a selection from the list. I need adding from the page of item.

> I'm a bit stuck in architecture.
> Please help.

Comment: Without seeing any code we are not sure what's going on with your mind.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [session (request.session)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/http/sessions/)

I would define a `Basket` model. When a session is new it does not contain a basket list. Create a new empty default basket and store its id in the session's basket list and also its active basket. Then you can always add to the current basket, and you can implement (a) view(s) for creating, deleting, and (re)naming baskets and for choosing the current one.

If you wanted you could persist baskets for logged-in users by having a foreign key to `User` and retrieving all the user's baskets to his session on login.

I don't know what you are up to but you might consider giving the user shopping lists rather than baskets (like Amazon.com does). Make it easy for a user to pop anything he is looking at onto one of his lists. Later he can view his list, and delete or purchase items from it.